# The reference assemblies for framework “.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1” were not found in RHPL

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core

we have install [dotnet sdk](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux) in our RHPL version 7. when we try to build our project we getting some build error. my dotnet version on Linux is 1.0.4. we are getting error like this

```
    error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.
Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Comment: Does your project target .Net Framework 4.5.1 instead of .Net Core?

Answer (score 4):

Your project targets .net 4.5.1, in the csproj there should be something that looks like this

`<TargetFramework>net451</TargetFramework>`

That line would target the windows desktop based .net which will not compile on linux.

You need to have your project target `netstandard` or `netcoreapp` depending on your usecase.

If you have a `TargetFrameworks` attribute (note the `s` at the end) with a semicolon seperated list of framworks then it is likely multi targeted. You could probably call `dotnet build /p:TargetFramework=<FrameworkHere>` where the framework is in the list of frameworks and it starts with netstandard or netcoreapp.

You will not be able to compile netX code on linux, only `netstandard`, `netcoreapp`, and a few other obscure monikers.

Answer (score 0):

To target .NET framework (as opposed to standard/core), you will need to have at least part of Mono installed.
The simplest would be to simply install all of mono (version 5 or higher recommended) and use its msbuild instead of dotnet build.

At some point, the dotnet SDK should be able to find and use the Mono reference assemblies automatically (cfr. https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335); then you would only need those, not the full Mono environment.

As it stands, if you have the Mono reference assemblies installed (likely in a location like `/usr/lib/mono/4.5.1-api`), you should be able to do something like `dotnet build /p:FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5.1-api`.
If you're multi-targeting, you could set up a `<PropertyGroup>` in your project to set `FrameworkPathOverride` appropriately.

For example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MonoReferenceAssemblies)' != ''">
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net20'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/2.0-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/3.5-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.0-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.5-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.5.1-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.5.2-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.6-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.6.1-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.6.2-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.7-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471'">
    $(MonoReferenceAssemblies)/4.7.1-api
  </FrameworkPathOverride>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That way, `dotnet build /p:MonoReferenceAssemblies=/usr/lib/mono` would work regardless of target framework version (as long as the relevant reference assemblies are installed).